# How to create Text Box with hour format only (HH:mm) on vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a TextBox that work only with a date format (HH: mm)
That the user can only write Specific an hour (12:34) and not (12:65) or (1200) how can I do that?

The code is:

```
 Private Sub bTNOK_Click()

    TextBoxHour.Value = Format(TextBoxHour.Value, "HH:mm")

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    TextBoxHour.Value = "00:00"
    TextBoxHour.MaxLength = 5


End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the expectation for the time entry after 12:59PM? 13:00 or back to 1:00?

Answer (score 1):

Use Exit event

```
Private Sub TextBoxHour_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
        If IsDate(TextBoxHour.Value) And Len(TextBoxHour.Text) = 5 Then
        Else
            MsgBox "Input Hour like this Example 05:35"
            TextBoxHour.Text = ""
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I like this approach if the expectation is user can enter "13:03" etc, which makes sense. I might add this line of code before your if statement: `If Len(TextBoxHour.Value) = 4 Then TextBoxHour.Value = "0" & TextBoxHour.Value`

Answer (score 0):

A custom function that returns `True` or `False` would probably be best. If users enters something that returns `False`, have code go back and user enters new number.

This was about the best I could think of to defend against unsophisticated user entries.

```
Function CheckTime(inputasString) As Boolean

Dim theDoubleDotThing As Long

theDoubleDotThing = InStr(1, inputasString, ":", vbBinaryCompare)

If theDoubleDotThing = 0 Then
    GoTo NOPE
End If



Dim theHOUR As Long, theMinute As Long

On Error GoTo NOPE
    theHOUR = CLng(Mid(inputasString, 1, theDoubleDotThing - 1))
    theMinute = CLng(Right(inputasString, 2))
On Error GoTo 0

If Right(inputasString, 3) <> ":" & Right(inputasString, 2) Then
    GoTo NOPE

ElseIf theHOUR > 12 Then
    GoTo NOPE

ElseIf theMinute > 60 Then
    GoTo NOPE
End If

CheckTime = True

Exit Function
NOPE:


End Function
```

So putting this into your code....

```
Private Sub bTNOK_Click()

    If CheckTime(textboxhour.Value) Then

    textboxhour.Value = Format(textboxhour.Value, "HH:mm")

    Else
        MsgBox "what the heck is " & textboxhour.Value & "?!?!?", vbCritical, Title:="Come On Man"

    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT**
To help the OP I built a [sample file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gdB9y0qIvEWImzddFg) that has a button for a prompt and then tests the string.

Comment: Thank you but when I try to write a right time the boolean is false and it is open the error message like 12:24

Comment: @EranPeer, Sorry you're having trouble but I'm positive that text "12:24" would return `True`. Somewhere you must have the string saved differently. You'd have to see exactly what textboxhour.value really is. Perhaps it's in Date format. I built a quick file that tests the function. You click the button, enter text, and you get the result. Give it a try here (https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gdB9y0qIvEWImzddFg) hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a Boolean check as PGCodeRider suggested. Here is my suggested Function

```
    Public Function IsGoodTime(ByVal strInString As String) As Boolean
        Dim blnOut As Boolean
        Dim intPos As Integer
        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim strLeft As String
        Dim strRight As String
        Dim intLeft As Integer
        Dim intRight As Integer

        blnOut = True
        strTemp = Trim(strInString)

        intPos = InStr(1, strTemp, ":")
        If intPos > 0 Then
            strLeft = Mid(strTemp, 1, intPos - 1)
            strRight = Mid(strTemp, intPos + 1, Len(strTemp))
        Else
            strRight = Right(strTemp, 2)
            strLeft = Mid(strTemp, 1, Len(strTemp) - 2)
        End If

        intLeft = 0
        intRight = 0
        If IsNumeric(strLeft) Then intLeft = CInt(strLeft)
        If IsNumeric(strRight) Then intRight = CInt(strRight)

        If (Not ((intLeft > 0) And (intLeft < 13))) Then blnOut = False
        If (Not ((intRight > 0) And (intRight < 60))) Then blnOut = False

        IsGoodTime = blnOut

    End Function
```